# Passing variable to ON method (in jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, events

I'm trying to pass a variable(present in global scope) to a function(present in `on` method). I'm passing a data object to the `on` but it's not working. It's working if i take variable inside the function.

Here's the code:

```
var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
$("#firstName").on("blur keyup paste", {firstName: firstName}, function(){
    //access firstName
})
```

Also, what is the best way of using `on` method. Should i use it like i have used above or should i use it like this?

```
var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
$(document).on("blur keyup paste", "#firstName", {firstName: firstName}, function(){
    //access firstName
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the event is being raised on the element which has the value you're trying to retrieve you can use the `this` reference to get at it:

```
$("#firstName").on("blur keyup paste", function(){
    var firstname = this.value; // or $(this).val();
});
```

With regard to the usage of `on`, your first example is to be used when the element you're attaching the event to exists in the DOM. The second method is for when the element does not yet exist, but may do in the future. You should use the nearest static parent element for the primary selector though, not `document`.

Comment: is `body` fine as the primary selector(instead of `document`)?

Comment: It'll work, but it's not ideal. It should be the closest element to the one which was added which was available when the DOMReady event fired.